# Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'VALUE'

Tags: c#, sql, syntax

I m a beginning Developer, I m still studying and currently im stuck on a error. I'm learning a new technic on how to make proper `sqlconnections`.. but seems as i cannot find out whats wrong.

This is a simple program where, the user is scanning a bar code to fill a textbox. And depending on that value. Rest of the textboxes will be filled in.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code .Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'ProductBarcode'.

This is my code right now:

```
protected void PBarcodeTxt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        string cmd = "SELECT ProductNaam, ProductPrijs, ProductOmschrijving, ProductBarcode" +
                     "FROM Producten" +
                     "WHERE ProductBarcode LIKE '@Barcode'";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cstring))
        {

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, connection);
            command.Parameters.Add("@Barcode", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = PBarcodeTxt.Text;

            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
                rdr.Read();

                PNaamTxt.Text = (rdr["ProductNaam"].ToString());
                POmschrijvingTxt.Text = (rdr["ProductOmschrijving"].ToString());
                PPrijsTxt.Text = (rdr["ProductPrijs"].ToString());
                // PBarcodeTxt.Text = (rdr["ProductBarcode"].ToString());
            }
           finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command you are missing a number of spaces, try the following (notice the spaces before FROM and WHERE:

```
string cmd = "SELECT ProductNaam, ProductPrijs, ProductOmschrijving, ProductBarcode" +
                     " FROM Producten" +
                     " WHERE ProductBarcode LIKE '@Barcode'";
```

When you concatenate strings in this way you need to explicitly enter new lines and spaces, what you had before when concatenated would actually be:

```
string cmd = "SELECT ProductNaam, ProductPrijs, ProductOmschrijving, ProductBarcodeFROM ProductenWHERE ProductBarcode LIKE '@Barcode'";
```

Comment: That fixed a part of the problem :) thank you. Now i got a another error, i will try to fix that on my own first!

Comment: I'm glad it helped fix the problem. If you now have a different problem your best bet is to ask another question if you don't manage to solve it on your own, especially if it's an unrelated issue. This helps people in the future if they have the same problem as you because they can search for the exact problem more easily. It also helps you as people are more likely to answer an unanswered question :)